# React Component Re rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name, value);
    setContact((prevValue) => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: prevValue.lName,
          email: prevValue.email
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: prevValue.fName,
          lName: value,
          email: prevValue.email
        };
      } else if (name === "email") {
        return {
          fName: prevValue.fName,
          lName: prevValue.lName,
          email: value
        };
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Hello {contact.fName} {contact.lName}
      </h1>
      <p>{contact.email}</p>
      <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is a sample code for my question.
I have a JS object as a state variable.
What will happen if I only change email?
Only the paragraph element will be re-rendered or both paragraph and h1 (as the whole JS object is changed in setContact ) will get rerendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, everything.

```
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: ""
  });
```

because you are changing the entire object, which is the right way.

If you use separate state

```
  const [fName, setFname] = useState("")
  <H1Component fName={fName} />
```

if you only change fName, then `H1Component` will render.

For any component, if its `state` or `prop` changes, it get re-render. Then you ask next question, does the children get re-render? Repeat this process.